# Как выполнить заранее неизвестные расчеты в C#?

Tags: c#

Требуется выполнить заранее неизвестные расчеты в C# т.е. алгоритм по которому надо вычислять входящие параметры. Сам алгоритм храниться в базе данных. Как лучше это оформить? С динамическими вычислениями еще не сталкивался.

Например:
Проводиться психологическое тестирование и у каждого теста свой алгоритм, например 1-5(1 балл) 6 и 7 (2 балла) и алгоритм всегда разный для каждого теста свой. Сейчас это реализовано на Lua, но я понял что это не идеальное решение. А быстро реализуемый костыль.

Comment: Есть сферический конь в вакууме, требуется расчитать его плотность. Поподробнее можно. Ванга в отпуске.

Comment: Приведите хотя бы пару примеров.

Comment: Что-то типа своего языка в программе?

Comment: т.е. есть проводиться психологическое тестирование и у каждого теста свой алгоритм, например 1-5(1 балл) 6 и 7 (2 балла) и алгоритм всегда разный для каждого теста свой. Сейчас это реализовано на Lua, но я понял что это не идеальное решение. А быстро реализуемый костыль.

Comment: Постойте, а чем вам может не подходить Lua, может быть вы просто неправильно ей пользуетесь? Для приведенного примера с баллами, Lua более чем достаточна, зачем вы хотите тащить внутрь еще JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно вам подойдут [скриптовые языки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA) ([на английском](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language)) их много и разных.

Вы включаете в программу скриптовый движок и связываете его с функциями в вашем коде. Далее можно загрузить и выполнить скрипт, который сможет делать вычисления и обращаться к предоставленным функциям.

Comment: А могу ли я привязать к проекту V8 от Google и выполнять JavaScript внутри программы?

Comment: Для приведенного примера с баллами, Lua более чем достаточна, зачем вы хотите тащить внутрь еще JavaScript?

Comment: Т.е. не совсем я реализовывал Lua в программе, за меня это делал второй разработчик который больше проектом не занимается. Работает это так выполняется Lua вместе с JavaScript-ом в компоненте Web-браузер на форме и возвращает текст интерпретации.

Comment: А JavaScript нужен что-бы русский текст выводить, мне сказали Lua не поддерживает его.

Comment: Попробую реализовать самостоятельно, связку C# + Lua, спасибо за пищу для размышлений)

Comment: @ФёдоровАлексей Возможно вам стоит столкнуться с какой-то более определенной проблемой, сформулировать по ней конкретный вопрос и задать его здесь. Судя по описанию, вам нужно разграничить систему, чтобы части стали более самостоятельны. И не затаскивайте в Lua все подряд, по описанному примеру, вы должны подать на вход только номера тестов и выбранные пункты, и выдать итоговую цифру, текст вы можете прицепить уже снаружи.

Answer (score 0):

Я вижу 3 варианта:

1. Скриптовые языки (Python, например)
2. Если разновидностей алгоритмов не слишком много, то задать их все прямо в коде с различными параметрами (думаю, то что у одного теста за вопросы а-б х баллов, а у другого теста за вопросы k-m y баллов, это не разные алгоритмы). Я бы так и поступил.
3. Вынести логику обработки в SQL